# Running Python cgi-scripts everywhere in var/www/

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

Hey there!
I have a problem, I was not able to solve and I hope that here's someone who can help me.

I want to run my python scripts on my apache2-Server via cgi.

I know that I can add scripts into the cgi-bin Directory, but I want to run the scripts in every directory in the /var/www directories (also in the subdomain-directives).

What do I need to add to the config files in the Apache configs to add .py cgi-support?

I know there are many tutorials on the internet, but everyone adds different lines of code in different config files -.-

Thank you very much!

Philipp

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite a complicated question with no specific detail about it. What exactly is your  web server configuration? I mean - do you server server virtual hosts or just running one localhost instance?

In each case your definition of cgi scripts directory should point to the same directory:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /path_to_your_scripts/
<Directory /path_to_your_scripts/>
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

But to handle Python scripts I would recommend using mod_wsgi or mod_python. Google should point you to few tutorials how to use these.

Comment: ScriptAlias implies ExecCGI and you shouldn't need to set it again for the directory ScriptAlias refers to. The important thing is 'Options +ExecCGI'. Add ExecCGI to Options for directories referred to by Alias or DocumentRoot and OP will get what they want. The mod_python projects is dead and should really be avoided.